# What programming language would be ideal for making a note taking app for Ubuntu in which you use a wacom digitizer app?

Tags: programming, language-support, wacom

I have some, but not much experience in programming, so I decided that now that I will have some spare time, I'll choose one language and try to master it to a level. I am not sure which language should I choose as my first, so I thought the best way would be to have a goal in mind and as such I want to write an app, like onenote or xournal in which I could take notes with a digitizer pen with pressure sensitivity; such as the thinkpad yoga comes (can come) with. I would want to use that on ubuntu, hence my question. As I still don't understand a lot about specific language capabilities, I should ask, if there are significant differences regarding the digitizer pen? Is there a wacom sdk for specific languages or will I need to do it all alone? Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is like asking: "Which is the best candy?"  So you'll have a ton of answers, everyone debating each other over which is best, forgetting that this is about YOU: It completely depends on what **you** want to become.

There are 2 kinds of languages: interpreted and compiled.  One is easy to start with, the other one runs 1000 times faster.

So if you want to become a computer professional: C++ (compiled)

If you want to start a bit easier: Python (interpreted)